# How to Unit Test Exception Handler Middleware

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to use a custom error handler to return properly formatted exceptions for my .NET Core 3 API. The handler works great, the issue I'm having is with regards to writing proper unit tests to test the handler. I registered the middleware for this like so:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IEnvService envService)
    {
        if (envService.IsNonProductionEnv())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error-descriptive");
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        ...

     }
```

Here is the code for the 'Error Descriptive' endpoint:

```
    public IActionResult ErrorDescriptive()
    {
        if (!_env.IsNonProductionEnv())            
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This endpoint cannot be invoked in a production environment.");

        IExceptionHandlerFeature exFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

        return Problem(detail: exFeature.Error.StackTrace, title: exFeature.Error.Message);
     }
```

The issue I'm dealing with specifically is this line:

```
IExceptionHandlerFeature exFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work from a unit testing perspective, because (as far as I know) this line of code gets the most recent exception from the server. Is there a way I can somehow set the exception it gets from the HttpContext within my test? Also, since this is using HttpContext, do I somehow need to incorporate a mocked version of that as well, such as DefaultHttpContext?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by injecting the [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-3.1) interface in your Controller.
This interface provides an abstraction to access the HttpContext object, mostly outside your web libraries.

To use it you have to `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in your Startup file.
Then you can inject it in your controller.

```
[ApiController]
public class ErrorController
{
    private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> logger;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public ErrorController(ILogger<ErrorController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor){
        this.logger = logger;
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }
}
```

Then in your Method you use the HttpContext from the accessor interface instead the base class.

```
[Route("/error-development")]
public IActionResult HandleErrorDevelopment() 
{
     var exceptionFeature = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
     var error = exceptionFeature.Error;
}
```

Since we're now working against an injected interface, you can mock it out in your unit tests. Just remember you have to Mock the whole chain you're calling. (I'm using xUnit and Moq in this example).

```
public ErrorControllerTests() {
     this.httpContextAccessorMock = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
     this.httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();
     this.featureCollectionMock = new Mock<IFeatureCollection>();
     this.exceptionHandlerFeatureMock = new Mock<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

     this.httpContextAccessorMock.Setup(ca => ca.HttpContext).Returns(this.httpContextMock.Object);
     this.httpContextMock.Setup(c => c.Features).Returns(this.featureCollectionMock.Object);
     this.featureCollectionMock.Setup(fc => fc.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()).Returns(this.exceptionHandlerFeatureMock.Object);

     this.controller = new ErrorController(null, this.httpContextAccessorMock.Object);
}

[Fact]
public void HandleErrorDevelopment() {
    Exception thrownException;
    try{
        throw new ApplicationException("A thrown application exception");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        thrownException = ex;
    }
    this.exceptionHandlerFeatureMock.Setup(ehf => ehf.Error).Returns(thrownException);

    var result = this.controller.HandleErrorDevelopment();
    var objectResult = result as ObjectResult;
    Assert.NotNull(objectResult);
    Assert.Equal(500, objectResult.StatusCode);
    var problem = objectResult.Value as ProblemDetails;
    Assert.NotNull(problem);
    Assert.Equal(thrownException.Message, problem.Title);
    Assert.Equal(thrownException.StackTrace, problem.Detail);
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: You cannot use the `ControllerBase.Problem()` method. This implementation relies on the `ControllerBase.HttpContext` to retrieve a `ProblemDetailsFactory` object.

You can see it in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs). Since your Unit Tests does not have a context set, it will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

The Factory is nothing more than a helper to create a [`ProblemDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-3.1) object. Again you can see the [Default implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/DefaultProblemDetailsFactory.cs).

I ended up creating my own private method for creating this object.

```
private ProblemDetails CreateProblemDetails(
     int? statusCode = null,
     string title = null,
     string type = null,
     string detail = null,
     string instance = null){

     statusCode ??= 500;
     var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
     {
          Status = statusCode.Value,
          Title = title,
          Type = type,
          Detail = detail,
          Instance = instance,
     };

     var traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.TraceIdentifier;
     if (traceId != null)
     {
         problemDetails.Extensions["traceId"] = traceId;
     }

     return problemDetails;
}
```

The full Error Handling method looks like this.

```
[Route("/error-development")]
public IActionResult HandleErrorDevelopment() {
      var exceptionFeature = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
      var error = exceptionFeature.Error;
      this.logger?.LogError(error, "Unhandled exception");
      var problem = this.CreateProblemDetails(title: error.Message, detail: error.StackTrace);
       return new ObjectResult(problem){
           StatusCode = problem.Status
       };
}
```

For production I provide either a generic message to be displayed to the user, or I throw a custom handled exception in the code which already has a user-friendly message to be displayed.

```
if (error is HandledApplicationException)
{
    // handled exceptions with user-friendly message.
    problem = this.CreateProblemDetails(title: error.Message);
}
else {
    // unhandled exceptions. Provice a generic error message to display to the end user.
    problem = this.CreateProblemDetails(title: "An unexpected exception occured. Please try again or contact IT support.");
}
```