# How to make global error handling method - HandleErrorDevelopment from Microsoft guidelines, testable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception

I have an Asp.net Core 6 Web Api application.

Following Microsoft's [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-handler), I have added error handling for Development and other environments:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error-development");
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
}


[Route("/error-development")]
public IActionResult HandleErrorDevelopment(
    [FromServices] IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
    if (!hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var exceptionHandlerFeature =
        HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()!;

    return Problem(
        detail: exceptionHandlerFeature.Error.StackTrace,
        title: exceptionHandlerFeature.Error.Message);
}

[Route("/error")]
public IActionResult HandleError() =>
    Problem();
```

I have successfully added Integration tests. However, with Unit tests - the first method just seems untestable.

This part seems impossible to fake. I don't know why Microsoft didn't put a more testable version as an example.

```
var exceptionHandlerFeature =
        HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()!;
```

I saw this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288329/how-to-unit-test-exception-handler-middleware/61574643#61574643).

My question is - up until now is this the best way to refactor the method to make it more testable?

Since the answer is 2 years old - I decided to ask - maybe a better way has appeared?

Comment: as far as my opinion, the ans still holds good because to make it testable you need to mock the HttpContext and using IHttpContextAccessor is best way to do it.

Comment: After some research I agree. There is even an article here which recommends this way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0 if you want, you can post your answer, so that I can choose it.

Comment: i don't have any separate answer, since you have already mentioned the ans , i just provided my opinion.